# C client to C# server over TCP

Tags: c#, c, sockets, tcp

I have a simple TCP application. Client is written in C. Server is written in C#. I am sending a simple struct over TCP to server. Note that both C# server and C client are of socket type stream.

**Client in C:**

```
typedef struct 
{
unsigned short x;
float y;
char z[32];
}msgStruct;
```

Below is the send function in client.

```
msgStruct msg;
if (send(s, &msg, sizeof(msg), 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");
}
```

**Server in C#:**

```
private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
......blah blah bla......and finally
byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received); 
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

I did create same looking class in C# server but I have no idea how to use it in C#. Are there C# method like below from C?

```
recv_size = recv(new_socket, &msg, sizeof(msg)
```

If not, how do I do decode received buffers so that I can call msg.x in C#?

I know it is not a good idea to send a struct directly over socket. I still want to this without serialization. Both computer have the same endian.

Comment: "Client is written in C. Server is written in C#.", funny generally is the opposite ^^'

Comment: You can't just send data from client to server over TCP without opening a socket

Comment: What is the problem? Creating the TCP connection? Messing up data format? Wrong padding? Please be much more specific about where you struggle. And please also provide a sample that compiles...

Comment: I'd start at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx - I don't have a lot of experience with this but I think the way to go is to allocate some unmanaged memory and store the bytes there, then marshall to an equivalent structure in C#. (updated link)

Comment: I did have socket created. The code above does not show entire codes. The output on the server side is 32 weird symbols... I sent 32 byte of data from client to server. This tells me my C# server received the msg I sent but I am not decoding it correctly at the server side. Anyone knows how to decode it right?